# How to write this as a recursive Clojure function?

Tags: recursion, clojure, sum

I'll illustrate what I want to do using Python (I want to write this in Clojure). I have this function:

```
def f(n):
    s=0
    for d in range(1,n+1):
        s+=d*(n//d)
    return(s)
```

Which is basically looping from d=1 to n inclusive, and summing up the values of d times the floor of n/d.

In Clojure I want to make this a recursive function. Python equivalent:

```
def f(d, n):
    if d == 0: return 0
    else: return d*(n//d) + f(d-1, n)
```

and then I'd call the function with `f(n, n)`.

I am trying this:

```
(defn f
     ([n] (f n n))
     ([d n]
      (if (> d 0)
         (recur (dec d) n)
        0)))
```

But I don't know if this is right so far or where to slip in the sum or how to do it, etc.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you look at your Clojure `f` function, the `[d n]` arity recurs with

- `d` decremented and
- `n` unchanged

... until `d` is zero, when it returns `0`.

If we write this arity as a distinct local function, using `letfn`, we can drop  the unchanging `n` argument, picking it up from the `f` argument:

```
(defn f [n]
  (letfn [(g [d]
           (if (> d 0)
               (recur (dec d))
               0))]
    (g n)))
```

This produces the wrong answer of course, always returning `0`:

```
(f 10)
=> 0
```

But we can see where to put the sum in:

```
(defn f [n]
  (letfn [(g [d]
           (if (> d 0)
               (+  (* d (quot n d)) (g (dec d)))
               0))]
    (g n)))
```

We have to revert the `recur` to an explicit recursive call to `g`, as it is surrounded by the `+`.

But at least it works:

```
(f 10)
=> 87
```

---

> In Clojure I want to make this a recursive function.

Don't. I've done it above just to show you where the calculation fits in.

Explicit recursion is rare in idiomatic Clojure. Better use the functions that encapsulate its common patterns. I won't repeat what [Carciginate](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47248957/1562315) has given, but once you get used to threading macros, I think you'll find the following clear and concise:

```
(defn f [n]
  (->> (range 1 (inc n))
       (map (fn [d] (* d (quot n d))))
       (reduce +)))
```

---

By the way, a reasonable analogue of your Python code is

```
  (defn f [n]
    (loop [s 0, d 1]
      (if (> d n)
          s
          (recur (+ s (* d (quot n d))) (inc d)))))
```

Comment: For some reason, I just don't like the thread-last macro. I always tend to put the arguments I expect to be threaded as the first argument, but then if I have to do a map or reduce and it starts getting messy. Nice use here though.

Comment: @Carcigenicate The thread-last macro can easily be refactored into transducers, which OP might appreciate in future. I admit that's not the way to better performance here.

Comment: I've been writing Clojure for a little over 2 years, and have yet to ever touch a transducer, so I can't speak for them :/. And I shouldn't say I don't like the thread-last macro. I disagree with the design decision to make the coll the last argument in maps and reductions. For a couple reasons I think it would be better as the first argument.

Answer (score 1):

I managed to get 3 ways working. Unfortunately, this algorithm doesn't seem to lend itself to nice recursion.

To get safe recursion, I had to introduce a third parameter. I just couldn't get it arranged so the `recur` was in the tail position. I also decided to count up instead of down.  I don't think there's anything left field here, although it did get quite long unfortunately.

```
(defn f3
  ([n] (f3 n 1 0))
  ([n d s]
   (if (> d (inc n))
     s
     (recur n (inc d)
            (+ s (* d (quot n d)))))))

(f3 10)
```

---

If unsafe recursion is ok, this can be simplified quite a bit. Instead of adding multiple argument lists, I decided to allow `d` to be defaultable using `& [d?]]` and a check later down. I tend to avoid adding multiple argument lists since par-infer has a difficult time handling the indentation required to make it work.  This trick isn't possible with the first way due to how `recur` handles var args. It only works if you're not using `recur`, or you do use `recur`, but only destructure 1 var-arg.

```
(defn f2 [n & [d?]]
  (let [d (or d? 1)]
    (if (> d (inc n))
      0
      (+ (f2 n (inc d)) (* d (quot n d))))))

(f2 10)
```

---

Unless you *really* need recursion though, I'd just write it as a map and reduction:

```
(defn f1 [n]
  (reduce + 0
    (map #(* % (quot n %)))
      (range 1 (inc n)))))

(f1 10)
```

Which to me is about as neat as it gets (without using a threading macro. See Thumbnail's answer).

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
(defn f
 ([n] (f n n))
 ([d n]
  (if (> d 0)
     (+ (* d (quot n d)) (recur (dec d) n))
    0)))
```

Comment: I changed it to `(defn f
     ([n] (f n n 0))
     ([d n s]
      (if (> d 0)
          (recur (dec d) n (+ s (* d (quot n d))))
        s)))` which seems to work though (passing the sum through as an argument)